# This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build: Error: Cannot find module '../binaries/uws_linux_x64_115.node'

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, truffle, go-ethereum, ganache

I am trying to migrate truffle contract to a ganache network. I have made changes to the truffle-congif.js file. I am using

Truffle v5.11.2 (core: 5.11.2)
Ganache v7.9.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v20.5.1
Web3.js v1.10.0

The whole output at console is

````
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module '../binaries/uws_linux_x64_115.node'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/node_modules/@trufflesuite/uws-js-unofficial/src/uws.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/core.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/migrate.bundled.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/original-require/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.



Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
Network up to date.```





I uninstalled and reinstalled truffle to fix it but i didn't work. I am not sure why this arises.
````